# quoteInto() and Zend_DB generate error

Tags: zend-db

I have written a piece of code to see if the record is already in the db, the code is like this :

```
$sql = $dbRead->quoteInto('SELECT email FROM betaEmail WHERE validate = ?'.$_POST['validate']);
```

and for connection, I am using Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql . The following error is generated, what should I make out of it? Any solution?

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::quoteInto(), called in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myform/user_registration.php on line 16 and defined in
/Users/payam/php_library/ZendFramework-1.11.8/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
on line 927
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.` to a `,`:

```
$sql = $dbRead->quoteInto('SELECT email FROM betaEmail WHERE validate = ?', $_POST['validate']);
```